# Blackberry Development: Architecture Best Practices and Patterns

Tags: java, blackberry, dependency-injection, tdd

As Blackberry developers we start the day with a much smaller toolbox than your everyday mobile developer. In addition the J2ME constraint means that we aren't able to take advantage of one of Java's core "features": an abundance of third-party frameworks including Guice.

That being the case, **what are the best practices in app architecture for the Blackberry platform?**

I'm looking for core frameworks and/or principles that answer perennial architecture questions like:

- How do we do dependency injection?
- How do we do test-driven development?
- How do we manage multiple API versions?
- How do we sneak in or emulate our favorite features from other Java versions?

**Please highlight one principle or best practice per answer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a presentation where I touch on some of these topics at BlackBerry DevCon'10:

- [Layout, Configure and Build Strategies for BlackBerry Apps](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B8tGCtzeoh3iZWE1ZjcxMDQtOWM1YS00Y2I1LTk0YTYtZDQzNmNiYmFiNmRi&hl=en)
- [Transcript of the talk](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B8tGCtzeoh3iMDEyNmI1ZWEtYzZiNS00MWZhLWEyMGYtNTcwMzAzZTdiZGY2&hl=en)
- [Sample code](http://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B8tGCtzeoh3iYTA2ZGIxOTMtNDQzMC00OTE4LWFiOTEtYmFlZjI0YjNiOWRj&export=download&hl=en)

In this presentation, I touched on various techniques for managing multiple API versions using libraries and use of abstract factories that dynamically instantiate at runtime.  I also offered some creative solutions to certain problems that arise when managing API versions across the inheritance hierarchy of BlackBerry Screen classes.  In addition, I offered an example of how I do unit testing using J2MEUnit and a custom-written (and source-provided) test console GUI that runs in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

**[Retrotranslator](http://retrotranslator.sourceforge.net/)** has improved my development setup.

I got the idea from AtomicObject's [Our Blackberry Development Environment](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/11/04/our-blackberry-development-environment).

I never got enums to work at all, and most Collections aren't usable, but generics and annotations save the day.